# Singular behavior of pure gravity

Tags: quantum-field-theory, gravity, matrix-model

Can anyone plese explain what means singular part of partition function for pure gravity?

Let me specify my question. I am dealing with 2D quantum gravity and starts from path integral formulation of this gravity with standard Einstein-Hilbert action. The path integral goes over all manifolds, also with non-zero genus $h$. The key moment is to show
$$\sum_h\int\mathcal{D}[g]\rightarrow \sum_{\text{triangulations}},$$
then one can work with matrix model that generate all possible triangulations and show that
$$\mathcal{Z}_G\sim \ln\mathcal{Z}_{\text{MM}}\equiv F,$$
where $\mathcal{Z}_G$ is 2D gravity partition function and $\mathcal{Z}_{\text{MM}}$ is matrix model partition function. Then, it is straighforward to show
$$F=\sum_{h=0}^{\infty} N^{2-2h}F_h,$$
where $F_h$ describes discretization of surface with genus $h$. Then, from all books, papers, etc. which I have seen, every author just state that (for instance matrix model potential is $V(M)=M^2/2+gM^3/3$
$$F_h\sim F_h^{\text{reg}}+(g_c-g)^{\chi(2-\gamma)/2},$$
where $\chi$ is the Euler characteristic of surface and $\gamma$ is certain number and this expression is true in continuum limit (number of triangulations goes to infinity).

It is totally unclear for me how I can show this fact and what is the physical meaning of singular part? It is can be shown that if we start from the Einstein-Hilbert action, coupling constant $g$ relates to cosmological constant $\Lambda$ (actually, $g=e^{-\Lambda}$).

To be more concrete, I refer to [this notes](https://arxiv.org/abs/hep-th/9306153).